# How to make a tezos node set CORS headers

Tags: rpc, node

I’m running a test sandbox locally. Anyone know an easy way to make my sandbox RPC service add a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header so that I can avoid CORS errors while testing locally?

[rpc.tzbeta.net](https://rpc.tzbeta.net/monitor/bootstrapped) seems to add the header, so I can access it from my web app just fine, but it isn’t currently running the latest proposal code, so I can’t use it for testing.

One option for testing would be [a proxy](https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere), but if there is a way to tell the RPC service to do it for me, that would be ideal.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to start the node with these options: `--cors-header='content-type' --cors-origin='*'`.

Once you’ve started the node with these options the response headers should allow a JavaScript application to make RPC calls to a Tezos node.